# has_and_belongs_to_many works in form but not show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, has-and-belongs-to-many

My has_and_belongs_to_many doesnt work in my show view, In the form i am able to select multiple options but they wont display in the show.html.erb

My Section Controller

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :about, :name

has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

My Products Controller

```
 class Products < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :price, :name, :section_id

    has_and_belongs_to_many :sections
    end
```

In my show view

```
 <%=h @product.section.name %>
```

How do I display all chosen section when creating and showing a product

Answer (score 0):

You read this right? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

I think there should not be a `section_id` in the product class, but if you have a "special" section this might make sense.

If you did it right your friend is `@product.sections` (note the plural).

Cheers,